# Unable to run JDK file using AutoIt. Can anyone tell me what is wrong in this code?

Tags: automation, autoit

```
If $isSystem64bit = 1 Then
    $processID = Run("C:\Users\" & @UserName & "\Downloads\jdk-8u77-windows-x64.exe")

Else
    $processID = Run("C:\Users\" & @UserName & "\Downloads\jdk-8u77-windows-x32.exe")
EndIf
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please use code formatting and state your question in the text and not only in topic. Please be a bit more precise so that we are able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
#RequireAdmin

If StringInStr(@OSArch, "64") Then
    $processID = Run(@UserProfileDir & "\Downloads\jdk-8u77-windows-x64.exe")
Else
    $processID = Run(@UserProfileDir & "\Downloads\jdk-8u77-windows-x32.exe")
EndIf
```

Comment: Thanks, I have just started with AutoIt and I didn't realize that it would require admin rights..